Cannot Open Open File From Server Action in Next 14
I am trying to authenticate using google cloud. Per their documentation, I got the crendentials.json and for testing purposes I added to the root directory of my project.
here is the snippet of code that initiate the authentication:
"use server";
import { authenticate } from "@google-cloud/local-auth";
import path from "path";
const SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"];

export async function authorize() {
  console.log("process.cwd", process.cwd());
  const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), "credentials.json");
  console.log("CREDENTIALS_PATH", CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  try {
    const client = await authenticate({
      scopes: SCOPES,
      keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    });

    console.log("[authorize()] client returned => ", client);
    return client;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("ERROR => ", e);
  }
}

when I call this function from a client component, I get an error saying: Module Not Found.
The path is correct, I have triple checked. I am wondering if it's because it's a server action and it cannot access files in certain locations.
Should the file be somewhere else, and in production environment, where should the file be stored?
